# Connecting to HTML5 Websocket

Tags: html, websocket

I'm a bit confused about HTML5 Websockets. I've looked at numerous tutorials out there and a lot of them have different variations of connecting using different ports. What do these ports mean?

[Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/real-time-data-exchange-in-html5-with-websockets.html) for instance, uses this:

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1740');
```

Then another [tutorial](http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html) has this where no ports are required:

```
new WebSocket("ws://www.websockets.org");
```

And finally a third tutorial has a port, but it's completely different:

```
new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/echo");
```

My question would be, why do these vary? How do I know which ports to connect to? Also, I've attempted to do my own connection:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://test.ontarget-network.com/");
```

But I get the following error: `Unexpected response code: 200`

I've tested around and tried connecting to various other "ports" (not knowing what I'm doing obviously, typing in random numbers) and this error would disappear, however, my code

```
ws.onopen = function(){
   alert("Connection Established");
};
```

would not execute.

I'm trying to fully understand HTML5's Websockets API so I can experiment and create more dynamic applications. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A successful WebSocket connection relies on an initial response with HTTP status code `101` from the server.  Anything else should result in an error on the client.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following comes from the [latest WebSocket draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17):

> By default the WebSocket protocol uses port 80 for regular WebSocket
> connections and port 443 for WebSocket connections tunneled over TLS
> [RFC2818].

Really though, you should be able to use any valid port not in use. As long as clients are trying to connect to the same port that the server-side script opens for the socket connection, you should be fine.

A quick note on ports:

- Port 80 is the HTTP port.
- Port 8080 is the alternate HTTP port.
- Port 443 is the HTTPS (i.e., HTTP with TLS) port.
- Port 1740 in the Adobe code seems like some random port not already in use by other services.

For a full list of preset ports, please see the following:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

As for your "Unexpected response code: 200" error, I'm guessing that the WebSocket URL you're using on the client side is not pointing to a valid server-side script, but that's hard to comment on without more info.

Answer (score 14):

The server should have an endpoint that accepts WebSocket connections.   So, if that endpoint is `/echo` you would want to connect to:

```
ws://localhost:8080/echo/websocket
```

You will get the `Unexpected response code: 200` error if you exclude the `/websocket` suffix after the endpoint.  I was having the same confusion and [this link](http://procbits.com/2013/10/09/connecting-to-a-sockjs-server-from-native-html5-websocket) cleared things up a bit for me.

Comment: Yep, same thing happened for me.  +1

Comment: Man this one saves my life. I have spent hours figuring out what happened.

Comment: Same issue +1 from me

Comment: Same for me. But I wonder if this is some standard? When I'm writing server-side code, I never saw anything mentioning this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, But to survive with

```
Unexpected response code: 200
```

You need to have either server-side script to handle the web socket, or you can use **Node.js** to build a you server script.
for the sake of education you can try to biuld your own websocket sever script.

Answer (score -8):

Actually there is something else... You can not open a connection to every port since there is a list of blocked ports in every browser. I remember seeing the full list of ports in 'The tangled Web' from Michal Zalewski; however, I think a quick google will show this also.

Comment: This is just *wrong*! You can have blocked ports however if you are behind a corporate firewall. That is usually assumed not to be the case. If you can access any web page, websockets should just work!

Comment: Actually, he's right (although also irrelevant). Please see http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/PortBanning.html#portlist