# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions WebSocket

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, websocket

I am trying to implement WebSocket using Fleck Nuget Package. But I have hosted an API on my local IIS and Trying to access it in WebSocket code.
However I am getting below Error

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Below is the constructor code

```
    static HomeController()
    {
        var server = new WebSocketServer(91, "ws://192.168.1.132");
        server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.OnOpen = () =>
            {
                allSockets.Add(socket);
            };
            socket.OnClose = () =>
            {
                allSockets.Remove(socket);
            };

            socket.OnMessage = message =>
            {
                allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(message));
            };
        });

    }
```

I am clueless since I am attempting this for the first time.

Comment: Did you try to change the endpoint to tcp or check if the port is open ?

Comment: I am getting error **"failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200"**

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14554273/4906586) help? If you could check the sent header, can you confirm that you are sending an upgrade request? On the other hand a [valid websocket URI](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-3) requires a resource name: like `ws://myhost.com/some-path-to-endpoint-here` unless your endpoint is at the root but I think this is not recommended